# How to Re-Use MongoDB Queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Suppose I have a mongodb query as such :

```
db.collection('users').updateOne({name:name},{$set:{data:data}})
```

I want to use this query across many functions and I want to reuse it and avoid writing the same query over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use query only if you provide condition and object data in function. Check below code it may help you to get the same result.

**This will be your model function.**

```
user.updateUser = function (conditon, updateData, callback) {
  userModel.update(conditon, updateData).exec(callback);
}
```

**You can call this function like as below.**

```
userModel.updateUser({_id: userId, name:name},{$set:{data:data}}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err, result);
});
```